# BetterAuthorizationSample weird?

Tags: macos, authorization

I have a quick, newbie question...

I just started looking through authorization services and Apple's BetterAuthorizationSample...

for some reason, I just can't get the hang of it. For example...

I deleted the HelperTool and InstallTool and SampleTool.c and all references, but why does the program seem to continue work like nothing happened at all even after a clean build?

Even commenting out all the code in SampleT0ol.c doesn't seem to affect the way the program runs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless something's changed recently, BAS relies on a lot of files in a lot of places. Deleting them in Xcode isn't going to delete them from your system if you've installed them all.

Comment: OHH... 
I see now. Thank you so much!
I deleted the HelperTool in /Library/PrivilegedHelperTOols as well as the socket in /var/run and it works like it's supposed to now.
Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @Nano8Blazex, I have the same problem. How do you delete the "socket in /var/run" ? Thanks.

Comment: @David, it's been a while (I kind of stopped tinkering with this) but I think I just navigated to var/run and deleted the com.yourcorrespondingcompany.theawesomename.socket file.